# Generator in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator

I have the code:

```js
function countA() {
  return 1;
}

function* sendStuff() {
  let y = yield countA();
  console.log("y: ", y);
  yield;
}

var gen = sendStuff();

console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

The result is:

```
    > 1
    > "y: " undefined
    > undefined
```

Why y is undefined? as I know I should be 1 instead (get from countA result).
Please help me with it. Thank you a lot

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how `yield` works. You seem to be using it as if it's an `await` - instead it's sort of a replacement of the `return` statement. A generator function can have mulitple "return equivalents" and will simply return the first, then when you use `next`, you'd get the next `yield` statement and so on. `let y = yield countA();` means "return the value of `countA()` as the current value of this generator and assign the result of *this return operation* to `y`".

Comment: yep, I really dont understand the way that yeild works. Thank you for your answer, but I'm confused about this sentence: let y = yield countA(); means "return the value of countA() from the current value of this generator and assign the result of this return operation to y". Could you explain more please. I appreciate so much

Comment: Basically, treat `yield` as `return` but in a generator function. So `yield countA()` means `return countA()`. So, the entire line `let y = yield countA();` will declare the variable `y` and assign to it the result of `yield countA()`. This is not the same as the result of `countA()` but the result of the `yield` (remember `return`) expression. Since this is nothing, you get `undefined`.